# Do all periodic waves have a fundamental frequency?

Tags: waves, fourier-transform, frequency

Do all **periodic wave** forms have a fundamental frequency (if true, why?) and I was also wondering if a **pulse** also has a fundamental frequency?

Comment: All periodic waves have a fundamental frequency (or they wouldn't be periodic). But many real sounds are not periodic waves. Pedantically, no real sound is actually periodic because no sound has remained coherent from the beginning of the universe and is expected to continue to the end of the universe.

Comment: @user121330, the usual definition of a periodic function is one that has the same value $f(t_0 + n T)$ for any $0 < t_0 < T$ and any integer value of $n$. A sound that has a beginning or end does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: @ThePhoton [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) disagrees with you.

Comment: @user121330, except usually the reason we talk about periodic signals is to do Fourier analysis, using the Fourier transform (or series) which are based on the domain being the real numbers.

Comment: @ThePhoton If only there was some way to [shorten the domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) so that we could ever finish... Look, if you want to claim to be pedantic, you have to be ready for other pedants to come out of the woodwork. You'd agree that spherical coordinates cover all space. I hope you'd also agree that 2/3 spherical dimensions are finite. Are you suggesting that Fourier analysis doesn't work in spherical coordinates?

Comment: The ideal pulse is the Dirac delta distribution, which has no fundamental period: its spectrum is flat, i.e., it contains all frequencies.

Comment: Are you asking whether they "have" a fundamental frequency in the sense that power is present in the spectrum at that frequency, or whether they "have" a fundamental frequency in the sense that such a frequency can be defined for them?

Comment: @user121330  Please provide a more specific link to the part of the Wikipedia article that you want us to look at.  I can't figure out what I should be reading.

Comment: @garyp The part in the definition where it says 'in the domain'. You can choose all space, but that's just one of an uncountably infinite number of domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first look at a definition of "fundamental frequency": ["The fundamental frequency, often referred to simply as the fundamental, is defined as the lowest frequency of a periodic waveform."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency) Given this definition, all periodic wave forms definitely have a fundamental frequency $f$, which is exactly the reciprocal of the period $T$ of the periodic waveform $$f=\frac {1}{T} \tag 1$$ @ThePhoton has pointed this out correctly in his above comments. The reason is that any periodic waveform $$f(t)=f(t+T)\tag 2$$ with period $T$ can be expanded in a [Fourier series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Other_common_notations) with period $T$: $$ f(t)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n \exp( i\frac {2\pi nt}{T}) \tag3$$ where the coefficients are given by $$c_n=\frac {1}{T}\int_{t_0}^{t_0+T} f(t)\exp(-i \frac {2\pi nt}{T}) \tag 4$$ and the integral is over any period of the function starting at $t_0$. Thus the fundamental frequency waveform $f_1 (t)$ of an arbitrary periodic waveform $f(t)$ is given by the Fourier term for $n=1$: $$f_1(t)=c_1 \exp( i\frac {2\pi t}{T}) \tag 5$$ with $c_1=c_1*$ defined by eq. (4). A single pulse does't have a fundamental frequency in this sense. It can, however, be decomposed into infinitely many frequency components that correspond to the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform) of the single pulse.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean.

If you're feeling mathy, you might see **periodic waves** and think [periodic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function), $f(x) = f(x + p)$, and [fundamental frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_frequency) and think 'if it doesn't have a fundamental, it's not periodic.' In math, given $f(x) = f(x+p_1)$, and $g(x) = g(x+p_2)$, $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$ is not periodic unless $\frac{p_1}{p_2} \in $ rationals$^1$, despite $h(x)$ being composed of periodic functions. QED. Yes.

If you were coming from a musical or electronics background, you might see 'periodic wave' as a 'signal' with periodic properties - this makes more sense given the OP asks about fundamental frequencies which are a common topic for musicians. Here, the fundamental is the tone which the human ear identifies as the specific pitch of the signal (because it's the loudest [lowest] psycho-acoustically).

The one dimensional wave equation, with its famous set of '[overtones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))', approximates string, brass and wind instruments. The fundamental is the lowest frequency in the harmonic series. [Round percussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1) and [square percussion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaveEquationRectangle.html) have different, more complicated overtones. For this reason and decay, describing these signals by their fundamentals may be less useful, but they do have a lowest frequency which usually decays more slowly than the higher frequency components. Not necessarily.

Incidentally, we tune most pianos to [equal temperament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equal_temperament) which means that adjacent notes have a ratio of $\root{12}\of{2}$. To generate a signal without a fundamental frequency, simply play any two notes that aren't integer octaves apart. Trivially, testably no.

If you had a background in wavelets, solitons or acoustics, you might include [periodic travelling waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_travelling_wave)$^2$. OP, is this what you mean when you say 'pulse'? Here, the only requirement is that the frequency components have similar speeds in the medium. These probably aren't periodic *functions* because a wavelet needn't repeat. A pulse will have a 'lowest frequency', but the pulse's duration may be too short to identify that frequency - see ears and [NSST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem). Still no.

Last, if we're talking about sound and being pedantic, our ears have hairs that vibrate at different frequencies, so rather than 'no sound is periodic', every sound is necessarily periodic. If you managed to play [Dirac's delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), first of all, wow and nice explosion, but your ear would hear it's own frequency response characteristic. This and hitting a system with a Heaviside Step function are techniques for quickly examining a system's frequency response.

$^{^1\text{Irrationals are uncountable while rationals are merely infinite. Given 2 random frequencies, the signal's assuredly non-periodic.}}$

$^{^1\text{Travelling waves exist with open and closed boundary conditions.}}$

Comment: If you superimpose two waves whose frequencies vary by a rational number factor, the resulting wave is periodic, and will have a fundamental frequency.  If the frequencies differ by an irrational factor, the resulting wave is not periodic, and does not have a fundamental frequency.  A periodic function *has* a fundamental frequency.  Nonetheless, I think the mention of a *pulse* might mean that we are not properly interpreting the OP's question.

Comment: @garyp Rational numbers are more sparse than stars in the sky of irrational numbers.